# Filter numpy ndarray with another ndarray, row by row

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, filter, sub-array

I have 2 numpy ndarray

The first contain x and y values :

```
xy_arr = [[ 736190.125         1130.        ]
 [ 736190.16666667    1130.        ]
 [ 736190.20833333    1130.        ]
...,
 [ 736190.375         1140.        ]
 [ 736190.41666667    1140.        ]
 [ 736190.45833333    1140.        ]
 [ 736190.5           1140.        ]]
```

the second have x y and index values and is much bigger than the first:

```
xyind_arr = [[  7.35964000e+05   1.02000000e+03   0.00000000e+00]
 [  7.35964042e+05   1.02000000e+03   1.00000000e+00]
 [  7.35964083e+05   1.02000000e+03   2.00000000e+00]
 ..., 
 [  7.36613397e+05   1.09500000e+03   3.07730000e+04]
 [  7.36613404e+05   1.10000000e+03   3.07740000e+04]
 [  7.36613411e+05   1.10500000e+03   3.07750000e+04]]
```

I want to keep all rows of the xyind_arr where values are same in xy_arr like :

> (xyind_arr[:,0] == xy_arr[:,0]) and (xyind_arr[:,1] == xy_arr[:,1])

My code :

```
sub_array = xyind_arr[((xyind_arr[:, 0] == xy_arr[:, 0]) &
                       (xyind_arr[:, 1] == xy_arr[:, 1]))]
```

Only work if the xy_array have one element.
For example :

```
import numpy as np

xy_arr = np.array([[56, 400]])
xyind_arr = np.array([[5, 6, 0],[8, 12, 1],[9, 17, 2],[56, 400, 3],[23, 89, 4]])

sub_array = xyind_arr[((xyind_arr[:, 0] == xy_arr[:, 0]) &
                       (xyind_arr[:, 1] == xy_arr[:, 1]))]

print(sub_array)
```

result OK :

```
[[ 56 400   3]]
```

But with

```
xy_arr = np.array([[5, 6],[8, 12],[23, 89]])
```

The result is

```
[]
```

And I expected

```
[[5, 6, 0],[8, 12, 1],[23, 89, 4]]
```

Is there any clean numpy method to obtain this filtered sub array ?

---

Edit :

Finally I let down the numpy solution and use the python set() :

```
    xy_arr_set = set(map(tuple, xy_arr))
    xyind_arr_set = set(map(tuple, xyind_arr))
    for x, y, ind in xyind_arr_set:
        if (x,y) in xy_arr_set:
            "do what i need"
```

Comment: Please post data that is actually valid Python code.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: the output is all rows of xyind array where xyind_array.x == xy_array.x and xyind_array.y == xy_array.y

Comment: It looks like you want to filter `xyind_arr` by a condition of *`tuple` equality*. You need the first column and second column to exist together, like a compound key, in the smaller array in a single row. Converting `xy_arr` into some type of `set` or `dict` structure that allows this to be looked up efficiently will be a much better bet than shoe-horning it into complex numpy filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) but it tests only against a scalar array; there is no tuple-comparison in it. You could use this method to find all rows of Array1 where the 0th column entry is in 0th column of Array2, and also the 1st column entry is in 1st column of Array2. But this is different from your task, because there is no guarantee that both 0th and 1st entry were found *in the same row* of Array2.

Since `xyind_arr` is much larger, I think it should be acceptable to loop over the smaller array `xy_arr`, applying one of the `xy_arr` filters at a time, and concatenate the results. For this to work, the rows of `xy_arr` must be unique, so better check that first:

```
xy_arr = np.unique(xy_arr, axis=0)    
sub_array = np.concatenate([xyind_arr[(xyind_arr[:, 0] == xy_arr[k, 0]) &
                            (xyind_arr[:, 1] == xy_arr[k, 1])]
                            for k in np.arange(xy_arr.shape[0])], axis=0)
```

Note: the order of rows will not be preserved.